# Dynamically choose object type

Tags: oop, fortran, object-type

I'm trying to make flexible user interface for numerical solver. The problem is that I cannot formulate how to implement dynamic choosing of initial condition geometry (rectangular, sphere etc). I've tried to use abstract class `initial_conditions_geometry` as a parent with child classes `rectangular` and `sphere` which specify certain attributes and implement method `in_bounds` for geometry:

```
type    ,abstract   ::  initial_conditions_geometry
    contains
        procedure (in_bounds)   ,deferred    :: in_bounds 
end type

abstract interface 
    logical function in_bounds(this,coordinates)
        import :: rkind
        import :: initial_conditions_geometry
        class(initial_conditions_geometry)  ,intent(in) :: this
        real(rkind)     ,dimension (:)      ,intent(in) :: coordinates
    end function in_bounds
end interface

type    ,extends(initial_conditions_geometry) :: rectangular
    integer ,dimension(:,:) ,allocatable    :: rectangular_bounds
contains
    procedure   :: in_bounds => in_bounds_rectangular
end type 

type    ,extends(initial_conditions_geometry) :: sphere
    integer ,dimension(:,:) ,allocatable    :: sphere_bounds
    integer ,dimension(:)   ,allocatable    :: sphere_center
contains
    procedure   :: in_bounds => in_bounds_sphere
end type

interface rectangular
    procedure constructor_rectangular
end interface

interface sphere
    procedure constructor_sphere
end interface
```

Here is `initial_conditions_layer` class definition, which encompasses initial condition geometry and distribution:

```
type    :: initial_conditions_layer
    class(initial_conditions_geometry)  ,allocatable    :: layer_geometry
    type(initial_conditions_distribution)               :: distributor
end type   

interface initial_conditions_layer
    procedure   constructor
end interface
```

The question is: how can manage to create constuctor for `initial_conditions_layer` that dynamically (depending on geometry type in some text file) sets `layer_geometry` type (rectangular, sphere etc) ?

**Edit**
Maybe it is useful to add some of my attempts to solve this problem.
I've tried to organize constructor for initial_conditions_layer object as follows:

```
type(initial_conditions_layer) function constructor(dimensions,layer_number,initial_conditions_data_file_unit)
    integer ,intent(in) :: layer_number
    integer ,intent(in) :: initial_conditions_data_file_unit
    integer ,intent(in) :: dimensions
    character(len=20)   :: layer_distribution_type
    character(len=20)   :: layer_geometry_name     

    call get_layer_properties(initial_conditions_data_file_unit,layer_number,layer_geometry_name,layer_distribution_type)

    select case(layer_geometry_name)
    case('rectangular')
        allocate(rectangular::constructor%layer_geometry)
    case('sphere')
        allocate(sphere::constructor%layer_geometry)
    end select

    select type(constructor%layer_geometry)
    type is(rectangular)
        constructor%layer_geometry = rectangular()
    type is(sphere)
        constructor%layer_geometry = sphere()
    end select
end function
```

But this requires associate_name in select type construct. Associate_name should be a pointer to initial_conditions_geometry, but one cannot set target attribute to derived type field.

Comment: Do you mean something like (excusing the comment-code and implicit stuff): `if (geom.eq.'rectangle') allocate(rectangular::layer%layer_geometry)`? That's clearly not the full answer, but I'm wondering whether I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes ! But I've not found the way to implement it in `select type` construct, because it requires pointer `associate-name`.. And i cannot declare variable `class(initial_conditions_geometry)  ,allocatable  ,pointer  :: geometry` inside constructor as it would require to set target attribute for `layer_geometry` but this is forbidden by standard.

Comment: I think you'll have to edit your attempt(s) into the question, as I'm afraid I don't follow.  But in a constructor for `initial_conditions_layer` on what are you trying to `select type`?

Comment: Yep, sorry, I suppose I've confused you. I've tried to use select type in `initial_conditions_layer` constructor on `layer_geometry` attribute. I'll add my attempts into the question.

Comment: I haven't time to answer properly, but note the possibility of, say, `allocate(constructor%layer_geometry, source=rectangular(...))`.  No `select type` required.  (Has compiler-killing potential.)

Comment: Well, actually it worked ! :) I am not sure that my code uses polymorphism in a proper OOP way .. but still Thank You ! If you edit your comment in an answer form I wouldn't have any option but to check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is quite close to working, and I think you merely have a misunderstanding.

> But this requires associate_name in select type construct. Associate_name should be a pointer to initial_conditions_geometry, but one cannot set target attribute to derived type field.

An `associate-name` is required in this case but, regardless of the `=>` syntax, no pointer is involved.  You could then, without other changes, have

```
select type(clg => constructor%layer_geometry)
type is(rectangular)
    clg = rectangular()
type is(sphere)
    clg = sphere()
end select
```

Alternatively, in this simple case it is possible to do away with the `select type` construct completely, and handle things in the `select case` you already have.

Using sourced allocation with each constructor:

```
select case(layer_geometry_name)
case('rectangular')
    allocate(constructor%layer_geometry, source=rectangular())
case('sphere')
    allocate(constructor%layer_geometry, source=sphere())
end select
```

Or even

```
select case(layer_geometry_name)
case('rectangular')
    constructor%layer_geometry = rectangular()
case('sphere')
    constructor%layer_geometry = sphere()
end select
```

if you have the compiler support for intrinsic assignment to polymorphic variables (or by using defined assignment).

Comment: Thanks again, very useful answer ! I've checked all cases you proposed and all of them work absolutely fine !

Comment: No, i think that solution with select type is most powerful because one can see `clg` parameters under debugger. Otherwise `constructor%layer_geometry` recieves `rectangular` type but debugger still cannot show rectangular parameters of `constructor%layer_geometry`. I've tried something like this, but have got some weird errors.. maybe I fixed them while developing and now everything is ok.